# Как подключить скрипты в AssetBundle виджета?

Tags: yii2, assets

Есть структура:

```
- widgets
  - assets
    - js
    - css
    Test1Asset.php
    Test2Asset.php
  - views
  My1Widget.php
  My2Widget.php
```

В `My1Widget` я например хочу подключить `Test1Asset`, в котором должны быть прописаны  правильно пути до ресурсов `js` и `css`. Обычно в стандартных ассетах пишут

```
public $basePath = '@webroot';
public $baseUrl = '@web';
public $css = [
    'css/site.css',
];
public $js = [
    'js/test';
];
```

Но когда всё располагается в виджетах, в т.ч. ассеты - непонятно, что прописывать, ибо все попытки приводят к 404, то есть неправильные пути.

Что и где необходимо прописать, чтобы в АссетБандлподключить пути до ресурсов, а во view виджета подключить этот самый АссетБандл? Может как-то надо его публиковать и оттуда забирать?

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал виджеты группировать по директориям. Если все складывать в widgets, то будет каша. Когда-то будет 20 или 30 виджетов.

Comment: @fedornabilkin да, как вариант, надо рассмотреть, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если каталог, содержащий исходные файлы ресурсов, недоступен через интернет, укажите свойство `sourcePath`:

```php
public $sourcePath = '@app/pathToMyWidget';
```

Устанавливая это свойство, AssetManager будет публиковать исходные файлы ресурсов в доступном через Интернет каталоге автоматически, перезаписывая `basePath`, так-что больше вам ничего указывать не нужно кроме самих исходных файлов в свойствах `css` и `js`. Если вы не установите это свойство, это означает, что исходные файлы ресурсов расположены в `basePath`;

P.S.: все это вы могли бы прочитать сами в комментариях к классу AsssetBundle, вы от него наследуетесь.

Comment: Еще такой вариант `$this->sourcePath = __DIR__;`, тогда не надо зависеть от названия виджета и его расположения.

Comment: @fedornabilkin думаю это лишь пример. Я, например, в основном конфиге написал alias - `'@widgets' => '@app/widgets',`, а в бандле написал `public $sourcePath = '@widgets/assets';`

Comment: Это тоже хорошо, но `__DIR__` будет работать быстрее. Потому что в родителе `init()`  обрабатывает алиасы и получается, что механизм алиасов запускается дважды.